# Type is one of several concrete functions

Tags: typescript

Is there a mechanism in Typescript for statically declaring that an argument is one of several concrete *non-primitive* values? For example, the function `route()` can only be called with one of the functions `home()`, `about()`, or `contact()`, none of which have a specific unique type signature.

```js
function home () { return <h1>Home</h1>; }
function about () { return <h1>About</h1>; }
function contact() { return <h1>Contact</h1>; }

type Paths = /* one of home, about, or contact */
function route(path: Paths) {/* ... */}
```

`Enum`s are the spirit of my wish, but they are not the answer because they can only serialize primitive values:

```
enum Paths {
  HOME = home /* home cannot be assigned */
  ABOUT = "about" /* only works for strings */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have general [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which is what you'd need to specify a type as a union of *arbitrary* values.  As defined, your `home`, `about`, and `contact` functions are all of type `() => JSX.Element` and cannot be distinguished from each other or other functions of the same type.  If you can't change the type definitions of these functions, then you're stuck.

Assuming that you can alter the definitions of these functions, though, you can use [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) or [unique symbol types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) to [brand](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) values so that their types can be distinguished from otherwise-identical types.  [Unit types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) like primitive literal and unique symbol types in TypeScript can be used to get some of the expressiveness of dependent types.

For example, we can [dynamically add](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) a brand property to each one:

```
const idProp = Symbol("idProp");
function home() { return <h1>Home</h1>; }
home[idProp] = "home" as const;
function about() { return <h1>About</h1>; }
about[idProp] = "about" as const;
function contact() { return <h1>Contact</h1>; }
contact[idProp] = "contact" as const;
```

Here, `idProp` is a unique symbol (that you will presumably not export to others) and for each function we've added a property whose key is `idProp` and whose value is a different string literal.  This allows us to distinguish `home`, `about` and `contact` from each other as well as from unbranded functions.  If you don't care about distinguishing them from each other, you can make them all `true` or some other property value.

Now we can write

```
type Paths = typeof home | typeof about | typeof contact;
function route(path: Paths) {/* ... */ }
```

And you can see that it works on your branded functions:

```
route(home); // okay
```

But doesn't work on unbranded functions of otherwise identical types:

```
function nope() { return <h1>Nope</h1>;};
route(nope); // error!
```

If a malicious actor gets their hands on `idProp` and adds the right property with that key to their own function, they can fool the compiler into allowing their own function to be passed to `route()`.  Of course, a malicious actor can go through even less effort and just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that their function is of type `Paths`.  Thus, like the rest of the type system, this branding method does not guarantee type safety; it just makes it more probable.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI7hAHarzAAmACsWHAC8cAMoBPEACMIAGwAUAIm58IYBQEoacRgQCurfMDZwAFiSxz1cAN5xKMXVFZwAPCYCMAPgAS5lwHoPTy0AX0YzECwAbWV+AF0hOAUIrAUUdBZ2GHoGPQMYI2dkaV0YSxs7LAcnVyCAQRKYAKDQxmKIUpjeeMSFdtK0tDhMjhy8w2NMmDwyq1t7R2c3LwBhNmn8Zq9WhimZrpUwBOEFPfxBjLZRxkYYMTAsOB5kGBN0YTuHiAJTczgAHzgnyw3xQjQBQPuIJ+Z2yOn0E2cxFKFjALxMAC4nujUHN-EgAHRExD+OBhJgMZEwCwpTRwfykiAAa2QYhuuQRBWMrFUFjmlWqSyCADleVtgiEcowqRYeQ86Qy4FgoMQoABCIA)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use type assertions to (falsely) assert that these three functions have a particular type. Using an imaginary `__brand` property with a string literal type, where no real value will ever actually have that property with that particular string value, implies that the type can only be achieved by intentionally using a type assertion to say that the value is allowed.

```js
type PathFunction = (() => string) & { __brand: 'PathFunction' }

const home = (() => { return '<h1>Home</h1>'; }) as PathFunction;
const about = (() => { return '<h1>About</h1>'; }) as PathFunction;
const contact = (() => { return '<h1>Contact</h1>'; }) as PathFunction;

function route(path: PathFunction) {
    // path must be one of those three functions
}
```

Note that I've made the functions return `string` in order for the code to compile without React. You can change the return type of `PathFunction` accordingly.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgMQK4DsDGwCWB7dKAXigApSBKYgPigGdgAnHdAcyoDIoBvKAfT4AjRnHQATAFxQA5PCRosuAtKgBfAFDrMBBlER4AttBLkqRWr0YRgqRoWkAeRAEZqACUMQHAehfVpANxqVHB0sAgoGNj46AFaOsBQcIJ4qIkmlDQ8UFY2djJOrgCCKWk+foHBSWFykYoxcdrouk3AcNjEZJnm2bm29oXUAMIEbdjlrpWqITURCtEEceoAZlFKhIypwBCkYBFStfPrVNzqUOdQ3t5Qe0hQBqi6gtAEL8tQSHh00EhW0Kv1HTqDRAA)